# Cannot resolve method OnStartCommand()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a service in android API 22.
I getting error while trying to override the method OnStartCommand();
'**cannot resolve method**'.
When I don't override the method I am getting error '**method does not override method from super class**'. I am using Android Studio 1.5.1

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class BlockService extends Service {


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}



@Override
public void OnStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId){
    Toast.makeText(this,"service Started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }


}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx1hy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is case-sensitive. The method name is `onStartCommand()`, not `OnStartCommand()`.

Comment: Thank you , I feel so embarrassed to ask questions and find out it's a silly error.